# Mongo primary is showing behind the primary?

Tags: mongodb

Mongo primary is showing behind the primary ?? Its increasing as time passes . Please suggest ?

```
monRepl:PRIMARY> rs.printSlaveReplicationInfo()
source: xxxxxx:27017
    syncedTo: Mon Apr 27 2015 10:39:02 GMT+0530 (IST)
    **25835 secs (7.18 hrs) behind the primary** 

monRepl:PRIMARY> rs.status();
{
    "set" : "monRepl",
    "date" : ISODate("2015-04-27T12:20:38Z"),
    "myState" : 1,
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 3,
            "name" : "xxxxx:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 2,
            "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
            "uptime" : 329104,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1430111629, 90),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2015-04-27T05:13:49Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2015-04-27T12:20:36Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2015-04-27T12:20:37Z"),
            "pingMs" : 0,
            "syncingTo" : "yyyyyy:27017"
        },
        {
            "_id" : 5,
            "name" : "xxxxxx:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 7,
            "stateStr" : "ARBITER",
            "uptime" : 329104,
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2015-04-27T12:20:38Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2015-04-27T12:20:37Z"),
            "pingMs" : 0
        },
        {
            "_id" : 6,
            "name" : "yyyyyyy:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 1,
            "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
            "uptime" : 579120,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1430137238, 300),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2015-04-27T12:20:38Z"),
            "electionTime" : Timestamp(1429808169, 7),
            "electionDate" : ISODate("2015-04-23T16:56:09Z"),
            "self" : true
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: This is a question about administration of MongoDB, not about development of software using MongoDB. That means that this question belongs to https://dba.stackexchange.com. I voted to migrate the question.

Comment: Moreover: how can a primary fall behind a primary? You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too.

Answer (score 0):

It's the secondary which is behind the primary. You can tell by comparing the optimeDate of the primary (`2015-04-27T12:20:38Z`) with the optimeDate of the secondary (`2015-04-27T05:13:49Z`). As you can see, the difference is about 7.18 hours.

For *why* the secondary is so far behind the primary... good question. There are a ton of possible reasons.

Comment: Thanks Philipp for response . Will investigate more on delay on secondary.

Comment: We can make an educated guesses, though: A replication lag that big usually comes from nodes differing vastly in regards of disk IO performance. I'd guess one has SSDs and the other hasn't. The other most likely option is that the network is too slow for handling incoming queries and oplog traffic.